# Test case for utility classes in the DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, dll

I have a DLL project in visual studio. I have lot of nice classes inside it that helps the dll. Most of these classes are not exported and used internally by the dll to accomplish the task.

Here is the deal, with visual studio test case project, I was able to test only the exported functions in DLL and not the individual classes.

Can you suggest any way/workaround to unit test all the individual classes in a dll project ?

There is no solid way, so any nicer way is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question...

I managed to add them as existing item in a separate visual studio project and was able to build the exe. And I used [google test framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) to execute my tests. This way, I didn't change any code and at the same time I was able to test all the utility classes as an independent entity.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a utility dll, make them exported and test that or leave private (to the dll) and test them via the exported functions that use them.

Comment: 2 things,

1) I don't want to touch the util functions code. And I just need to test the public functions of util classes.
2) I can't test them via exported functions that use them. Consider an exported function that return bool and just accept a user info and store it into a db. And the util classes may range from db manager to logger. I just cannot test all of them via the exported dll functions. 

So, I want something which references these util classes and may be generate exe/obj/lib out of it and I can write my test functions on top of these obj/lib files.

Comment: Oh I would have considered that. So I'd have had data dll, and a logger dll and I woudldn't be forced to look for a hack so I could retrofit unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to build the project into a static library (.lib) instead of a DLL, and link the test project to that library. Doing so would allow the test project to access all of the classes in the library.

Of course, if you use this approach you would need to create a new, separate DLL that linked to the static library to perform the DLL exporting that's currently in place. This would likely require you to create wrapper classes/functions in the DLL that simply forward their invocations to the corresponding classes/functions in the static library.